# RVIZ shows odom frame fixed to map frame when running rtabmap

Tags: navigation, odometry, mapping, rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've set the map frame as the fixed frame in RVIZ, and this is what it looks like when running rtabmap https://imgur.com/a/U5fJLLP . This is what my partial tf-tree looks like https://imgur.com/a/1s2PnV8. This is my launch file for rtabmap:

```
<launch>    <!-- Choose visualization
-->    <arg name="rviz" default="true" />    <arg name="rtabmapviz" default="false" />    <arg name="local_bundle" default="true" />  <arg name="stereo_sync" default="false" />

   <param name="use_sim_time" type="bool" value="false"/>    <!-- Visual SLAM: args: "delete_db_on_start" and "udebug" -->  <node name="rtabmap" pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rtabmap" output="screen" args="--delete_db_on_start">
      <param name="frame_id"         type="string" value="base_link"/>
      <param unless="$(arg stereo_sync)" name="subscribe_stereo" type="bool" value="true"/>
      <param name="subscribe_depth"  type="bool" value="false"/>
      <param name="subscribe_rgbd"      type="bool" value="$(arg stereo_sync)"/>

      <remap from="left/image_rect"   to="/camera/left/image_rect_color"/>
      <remap from="right/image_rect"  to="/camera/right/image_rect"/>
      <remap from="left/camera_info"  to="/camera/left/camera_info"/>
      <remap from="right/camera_info" to="/camera/right/camera_info"/>
      <remap from="rgbd_image"        to="/camera/rgbd_image"/>

      <remap from="odom" to="/odometry/filtered"/>
      <param name="queue_size" type="int" value="30"/>
      <param name="map_negative_poses_ignored" type="bool" value="true"/>

      <!-- RTAB-Map's parameters -->
      <param name="Rtabmap/TimeThr"                   type="string" value="700"/>
      <param name="Grid/DepthDecimation"            type="string" value="4"/>
      <param name="Grid/FlatObstacleDetected"       type="string" value="true"/>
      <param name="Kp/MaxDepth"                       type="string" value="0"/>
      <param name="Kp/DetectorStrategy"             type="string" value="6"/>
      <param name="Vis/EstimationType"                type="string" value="1"/>   <!-- 0=3D->3D, 1=3D->2D (PnP) -->
      <param name="Vis/MaxDepth"                      type="string" value="0"/>
      <param name="RGBD/CreateOccupancyGrid"        type="string" value="true"/>
      <param name="approx_sync"                       type="bool" value="true"/>    </node> </launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299462/rviz-shows-odom-frame-fixed-to-map-frame-when-running-rtabmap/) by [asabet](https://answers.ros.org/users/35904/asabet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2018-08-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-08-02**:
Can you please copy and paste your launch file again, using the `101010` button instead of the `"`? The `"` button is for quoting and thus doesn't handle code snippets well.

**Comment by [asabet](https://answers.ros.org/users/35904/asabet/) on 2018-08-02**:
Done. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is normal, unless there is a loop closure, `/odom` and `/map` frames will be one over the other (meaning that odometry drift has not been corrected yet). See [REP 105](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html#map). When a reloclization/loop closure happens, the odometry corection will be seen between `/map` and `/odom`.

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2018-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4